# Ruby: Split binary data

Tags: ruby, binary

I want to split `data` to chunks of let's say 8154 byte:

```
data = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(some_very_long_string)
```

What would be the best way to do that?

I tried to use this:

```
chunks = data.scan /.{1,8154}/
```

...but data was lost! `data` had a `size` of 11682, but when looping through every chunk and summing up the `size` I ended up with a total size of 11677. 5 bytes were lost! Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regexps are not a good way to parse binary data. Use `bytes` and `each_slice` to operate bytes. And use `pack 'C*'` to convert them back into strings for output or debug:

```
irb> data = File.open("sample.gif", "rb", &:read)
=> "GIF89a\r\x00\r........."

irb> data.bytes.each_slice(10){ |slice| p slice, slice.pack("C*") }
[71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 13, 0, 13, 0]
"GIF89a\r\x00\r\x00"
[247, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51, 0]
"\xF7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003\x00"
...........
```

Comment: Isn't this going to be very slow?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but creates unneeded arrays and is extremely slow for big files.

This alternative works fine and is much faster (500x for a 1MB file and 10kB chunks!) :

```
def get_binary_chunks(string, size)
  Array.new(((string.length + size - 1) / size)) { |i| string.byteslice(i * size, size) }
end
```

For the given example, you'd use it this way :

```
chunks = get_binary_chunks(data, 8154)
```