# How to efficiently slice binary data in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

After reviewing SO post [Ruby: Split binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883868/ruby-split-binary-data), I used the following code which works.

```
z = 'A' * 1_000_000
z.bytes.each_slice( STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE ).each do | chunk | 
  c = chunk.pack( 'C*' )
end
```

However, it is very slow:

```
Benchmark.realtime do
  ...
=> 0.0983949700021185
```

98ms to slice and pack a 1MB file. This is very slow.

**Use Case:**
Server receives binary data from an external API, and streams it using `socket.write chunk.pack( 'C*' )`.
The data is expected to be between 50KB and 5MB, with an average of 500KB.

So, how to efficiently slice binary data in Ruby?

Answer (score 6):

## Notes

Your code looks nice, uses the correct Ruby methods and the correct syntax, but it still :

- creates a huge Array of Integers
- slices this big Array in multiple Arrays
- pack those Arrays back to a String

## Alternative

The following code extracts the parts directly from the string, without converting anything :

```
def get_binary_chunks(string, size)
  Array.new(((string.length + size - 1) / size)) { |i| string.byteslice(i * size, size) }
end
```

`(string.length + size - 1) / size)` is just to avoid missing the last chunk if it is smaller than `size`.

## Performance

With a 500kB pdf file and chunks of 12345 bytes, [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) returns :

```
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 28 seconds.
_eric_duminil is faster than _b_seven by 380x ± 100.0
```

`get_binary_chunks` is also 6x times faster than `StringIO#each(n)` with this example.

## Further optimization

If you're sure the string is binary (not UTF8 with multibyte characters like 'ä'), you can use [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-slice) instead of [`byteslice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-byteslice):

```
def get_binary_chunks(string, size)
  Array.new(((string.length + size - 1) / size)) { |i| string.slice(i * size, size) }
end
```

which makes the code even faster (about 500x compared to your method).

If you use this code with a Unicode String, the chunks will have `size` characters but might have more than `size` bytes.

## Using the chunks directly

Finally, if you're not interested in getting an Array of Strings, you could use the chunks directly :

```
def send_binary_chunks(socket, string, size)
  ((string.length + size - 1) / size).times do |i|
    socket.write string.slice(i * size, size)
  end
end
```

Comment: ((string.length + size - 1) / size) should be consider with + 1 space extra.

Comment: @nhp sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: For the #further optimization, the length of the array should be (string.length + size - 1) / size) + 1 or the result will miss the last (size) bytes

Comment: @nhp if there's an off by one error, I don't see it. Do you have a failing example, please?

Comment: @nhp: I tested it again. Adding `+1` will only append an empty string or `nil` to the array.

Answer (score 3):

Use `StringIO#each(n)` with a string that has `BINARY` encoding:

```
require 'stringio'
string.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
StringIO.new(string).each(size) { |chunk| socket.write(chunk) }
```

This only allocates the intermediate arrays just before pushing them to the socket.

Comment: Nice, I've never seen or used stringio before. This could come in a handy! Using `slice` appears to be faster by a factor 5 or so, but it still is a huge improvement compared to the OP.

Comment: This is slower but I prefer the declarative `StringIO` implementation...